# Selenium Server from website

Tags: php, curl, selenium, webforms, screen-scraping

Does anyone know of a simple way to send commands to a selenium server over a web interface? I am trying to automate the filling of several online forms (each requiring a login) but I don't want to do it from the local machine but rather a website so my employees can use it as well. This would save us time being that we currently fill out 8-10 different forms all with the same basic data. I have looked into form filling software but I really want this done by one server in the background. I don't think CURL would able to deal with the amount of DOM elements each website uses and some use those fancy ajax elements. I am pretty good at writing PHP, my original thinking was I could setup the selenium server with PHPunit and execute the scripts from any remote machine. I was sad to find this is still a command line only approach.

I appreciate any advice or technical info provided! Of course, if anyone knows of a better solution than selenium for automating web form filling by a server I would appreciate that info as well.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can create your own Web interface and submit the data in some remote database.
Then whenever you execute testcases it should take testdata from the database.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. My only problem is I am not sure how I would have the server ping the database to check for new request or to initiate a test case.

Comment: for that you can implement some CI tool to schedule your execution as per new some condition(like if new entry added in database).
you can also create a new table in database for log purpose which will increment flag if new test case added in database.
You can also implement listener if your unit test framework supporting it.

That is only what I am understanding from your comment . It would be better if you can elaborate your requirement if I am getting a wrong requirement.

Comment: No, I am going to do some research on what you just said. That sounds exactly what I was looking for. I would like it if the server could listen to the mysql tables until it sees a new entry, then launch a python or PHP script that works with selenium once a new entry is detected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HUDSON and integrate the selenium project in there. Hudson is a CI tool which has a UI and logins as per your requirement you can also create an individual login for your employees and just they have to login and click on a play button to fill the forms.